# Limit Slider TextBox Decimal Places

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have a Slider and Value TextBox.

[image]

It gives a value with 14 decimal places.

How can I limit (not round) the amount of decimals to 2? `75.89`

Limit it in the textbox, not process it after. And not snap to tick.

```
<Slider x:Name="slVolume" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Margin="0,92,48,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="66"
        Maximum="100" 
        />

<TextBox x:Name="tbxVolume"
         Text="{Binding ElementName=slVolume, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         Width="29" 
         Height="22" 
         TextWrapping="Wrap" 
         Margin="0,91,14,0" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Comment: I don't yet understand... do you want to limit the slider value (disallow any value with more decimal places), do you want to limit the displayed textbox value when it is transfered *from* the slider or do you want to limit the user input value when it is transfered from the textbox *to* the slider?

Comment: @grek see ASh's answer, `StringFormat=N2` limits it to 2 places in the textbox while it slides.

Comment: Then your question title is wrong, because you ask *"Limit Slider Decimal Places"* which doesn't happen.

Comment: @grek40 I see, I've updated the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add StringFormat to Text binding:

```
Text="{Binding ElementName=slVolume, Path=Value, StringFormat=N2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```